# regular expression for redirect common URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

How can we combine(make it generalize) these two redirection URL into one.

For Example:
URL1: `(?i)/MathBlog/10-common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/` => `/mathblog/common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/`

URL2: `(?i)/MathBlog/amp/10-common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/` => `/mathblog/amp/common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/`

Should become
URL3: `(?i)/MathBlog/{regex}/10-common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/` => `/mathblog/{/amp}/common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/`

`{/amp}` must be optional, i,e if `/amp` available then append to redirect url or just ignore it.

Comment: Do you mean `(?i)/MathBlog(/amp)?/10-common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/` => `/mathblog$1/common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students/`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`(?i)(\/MathBlog(?:\/amp)?\/)10-(common-math-errors-made-by-elementary-students\/)` => `$1$2`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/D2Za0n/1)